# Problem with ajv to read a variable that contains an object. Can someone help me? (lambda - nodejs)

Tags: node.js, lambda, jsonschema, json-schema-validator, ajv

In the "index.js" file I have:

```
 import { validatorFactory } from "./validator.js"; 
 import { authSchema } from "./schema.js"; 


export const handler = async (event, context) => {
 event.Records.forEach(record => {
    const { body } = record;
    
    console.log(body)

    
  const authValidation = validatorFactory(authSchema);
  const data = authValidation.verify(body);

 
  });
  return {};
};
```

As you can see, I receive an event (sqs message) and I am saving the record that arrives inside the body variable.

the console.log(body)

returns exactly this in the CloudWatch log:

```
2023-07-25T19:25:05.909Z    901a508f-8112-58be-806d-0db5a2d89a60    INFO    
{
    "Type": "Notification-test",
    "MessageId": "XXXXX-XXXX-XXX-XXXXX-XXXXXXX",
    "TopicArn": "XX-XXXX-1:000000000000:XXX-XXX-XXX-XXXXX",
    "Message": "<MESSAGE_JSON>",
    "Timestamp": "XXX-09-XXXX:48:54.800Z",
    "SignatureVersion": "X",
    "Signature": "EXAMPLEpH+..",
    "SigningCertURL": "https://sns.XXX-XXXX-XXXX.XXXXXX.com/SimpleNotificationService-0000000000000000000000.pem",
    "MessageAttributes": {
        "event_type": {
            "Type": "String",
            "Value": "XXXX-consents-XXX"
        }
    }
}
```

An object.
However, moving on to the next step, which would be using what is contained in the body variable to compare with the json schema, what I get is:

```
2023-07-25T19:25:06.213Z    901a508f-8112-58be-806d-0db5a2d89a60    ERROR   Invoke Error    
{
    "errorType": "Error",
    "errorMessage": "data should be object",
    "stack": [
        "Error: data should be object",
        "    at Object.verify (file:///var/task/validator.js:16:11)",
        "    at file:///var/task/index.js:16:31",
        "    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)",
        "    at Runtime.handler (file:///var/task/index.js:9:16)",
        "    at Runtime.handleOnceNonStreaming (/var/runtime/Runtime.js:74:25)"
    ]
}
```

I found it strange, because as shown in console.log(body)

this variable is saving the object I want to validate, so I copied that return I mentioned above and pasted it directly into the validation, like this:

```
  const authValidation = validatorFactory(authSchema);
  const data = authValidation.verify({
        "Type": "Notification-test",
        "MessageId": "XXXXX-XXXX-XXX-XXXXX-XXXXXXX",
        "TopicArn": "XX-XXXX-1:000000000000:XXX-XXX-XXX-XXXXX",
        "Message": "<MESSAGE_JSON>",
        "Timestamp": "XXX-09-XXXX:48:54.800Z",
        "SignatureVersion": "X",
        "Signature": "EXAMPLEpH+..",
        "SigningCertURL": "https://sns.XXX-XXXX-XXXX.XXXXXX.com/SimpleNotificationService-0000000000000000000000.pem",
        "MessageAttributes": {
            "event_type": {
                "Type": "String",
                "Value": "XXXX-consents-XXX"
            }
        }
    }
);
```

And as expected, it worked. But I just don't want to leave it fixed because I want each event that arrives in the queue to validate that it follows the expected pattern. I don't understand why it fails to get the value when I pass through the body variable.

Does anyone understand what could be going on?